# Filter table records column-wise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where I want to filter the rows on the basis of column values.

```html
<input id="searchInput" value="Column 1 Filter">
<input id="searchInput2" value="Column 2 Filter">
<br/>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        <tr>
            <td>cat</td>
            <td>one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dog</td>
            <td>two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cat</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>moose</td>
            <td>four</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using filter method of jquery :

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () { // or searchInput2
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
 // only filter on the basis of first column
        var $t = $("#myTable tr td:first-child")
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
})
.......
............
```

But it doesn't work property. Also I don't want to use any plugin like data table.

Comment: Why do you mean by "*it doesn't work properly*"?

Comment: I mean it doesn't filter records. It either hides or  shows all rows.